# Visual Studio package - Get the currently active document and edit it, inclusive peek definitions

Tags: visual-studio, plugins

I am developing a Visual Studio package which has to insert specific texts on user interaction.
Everything works so far. To insert a text, I just use:

```cs
TextSelection ts = m_dte.ActiveDocument.Selection as TextSelection;
ts.Insert("some text");
```

The problem is, if the user is editing in a peek definition window (It is a document like all others too, just shown inside the code), `m_dte.ActiveDocument` returns the top document, not the document in the peek window.

What can I change, that the selection object is always for the current cursor (for peek definition windows, too)?

If relevant: I am using Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current IWpfTextView from IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService like in this example: [Insert text into the current active text view](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#TextBufferInsert).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Using the IWpfTextView and its buffer seems to work, but the buffer has very limited functions (only inserting text on a specific position). I am using all the functions with line down, end of line, etc. to navigate. Is there any possibility to do so with the buffer?

Comment: @Fingeg IWpfTextView.TextViewLines gives you access to text lines.